# Workflow when chaining synchronous with asynchronous function with promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

What does the workflow looks like if I'd chain a synchronous and an asynchronous function with promises look like?

Case 1:

```
synchronousFunc(x).then(asynchronousFunc(resultOfSynchronousFunc));
```

synchronousFunc(x)

|----------|

asynchronousFunc(undefined)

|---------------|

Case 2:

```
asynchronousFunc(x).then(synchronousFunc(resultOfAsynchronousFunc));
```

asynchronousFunc(x)

|--------|

synchronousFunc(undefined)

|-------------|

Case 3:

```
 asynchronousFunc(x).then(function(){
  return synchronousFunc(resultOfAsynchronousFunc);
 });
```

asynchronousFunc(x)

|---------|

............synchronousFunc(resultOfAsynchronousFunc)

............|--------------------|

Case 4:

```
 synchronousFunc(x).then(function(){
  return asynchronousFunc(resultOfSynchronousFunc);
 });
```

synchronousFunc(x)

|---------|

asynchronousFunc(undefined)

|------------|

Comment: I don't understand your question. What (kind of) answer are you looking for? What is "*workflow*"?

Comment: Yes, all of your cases are buggy. a) Always pass functions as callbacks, not the results from a call b) synchronous functions don't return promises and you cannot chain `then` on them. Just use them like a normal function with a return value.

Comment: I'm looking for graphical visualisation like the one it is presented in this article (at the very bottom of the article) http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: What is with the diagrams in your question? Are those the timings that you expect and want to get validated/falsified?

Comment: Yes, they should be also like the representation in the article I posted.

Comment: Despite some comments to the contrary, there is nothing wrong with writing all these functions to at least *appear async* (and return resolved promised if they are synchronous). That will at least allow the consistent coding model you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets put asynchronous function is a function that returns promise (or `then`-able object, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)). Synchronous function is a function that returns any other result (not thenable).

Asynchronous function returns promise *"immediately"*, i.e. before promise is resolved (promise status is *"pending"*, `then` is not yet called).

```
funcSync(x).then(funcAsync) // Error if `funcSync` returns object without `then` method.

// Should be:

var res = funcSync(x);
var promise = funcAsync(res);
```

`promise.then(..)` as an argument takes function which works on result of asynchronous function: `fetchDataAsync.then( data => {..}  )`.
Case 2 should be:

```
fetchDataAsync(x).then(processDataSync);
```

It's too mundane to fix all your cases, just read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), please.